# Import Swift-file in Qt-Application

Tags: swift, qt, qml

I would like to integrate font recognition into my Qt application. Unfortunately I only know how to do this in Swift. Therefore I want to import the Swift file with the code for it into my already finished Qt application but I haven't found any information about how to do that.
I would be glad if someone can tell me how to do this or if font recognition through Apple Pencil is also possible in qt.
Thanks

Comment: You cannot 'import' swift file into c++/qt/qml these are absolutely different technologies.  You probably have to use some bindings (check [this](https://github.com/Longhanks/qlift) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55237121/how-to-integrate-swift-code-in-a-qt-application) ) or to make it as easy as possible some using some [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) mechanism.